# how do I fix fix error 0xc0000225 without reinstalling Windows?

Tags: windows-7, boot, 64-bit

I was partitoning an SD card and trying to make them both visible on windows 7
following this  guide [SD card second partition not recognized](https://superuser.com/questions/975900/sd-card-second-partition-not-recognized)

I used the x64 verison of Hitachi Microdrive x64 cause comments meantioned the link only being the 32 bit. I have windows 7 64 bit. I sware I didn't touch my computers normal drivers but something must of messed up because after a "restart"I got this boot error.

I don't have the disk and I'm in a panic ATM to try and get it back to normal- I can't remember how to boot into recovery mode with USB or run CMD

Answer (score 0):

For recovery mode is the F8 key.

Press the "F8" key repeatedly while the computer reboots and before the Windows logo appears. If you see the Windows logo, you mistimed the hotkey and must try again. If you're using a dual-boot system, select the appropriate boot partition before pressing "F8;" most users don't need to worry about this.
Press the up or down arrow keys to highlight an option from the Advanced Boot Options window and press "Enter" to select it.